# How to start thread for min latency

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running this c# code.

at some point, I have to web request POST to 3 different servers at the same time. as simultaneously as possible
for this, I am using

```
// t0
System.Threading.Tasks.Task k0 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>
{ 
   //web request first server  here
});
System.Threading.Tasks.Task k1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=> 
{
   //we request 2nd server here
});
System.Threading.Tasks.Task k2 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>
{
   //we request 3rd server here
});

// t1
```

my problem is it takes 13-15 ms to start the threads. (t1-t0) I am not very good at c#. most of my experience in writing this code and maintaining it.
can I decrease the time to start these threads?

Comment: Do you *need* the threads? The "code" inside each says webrequest, are you mostly waiting for I/O to complete? Or are you doing heavy CPU-bound processing as well?

Comment: None of this needs *threads* as written, use *IO completion ports* from the operating system via the *async and await pattern*

Comment: Why do you need it down to the millisecond? I mean the request probably needs to pass several servers before it reaches the destinations anyway.

Comment: These are not threads. These are tasks. `Thread != Task`

Comment: these are buy/ sell orders, fix like but through webrequest.  it will give the order than wait for  ack. i dont want to wait to send next orders to the second broker. i am looking io completion ports. thank thegeneral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `PostAsync` on `HttpClient` and awaiting all the tasks at the same time.

```
var responseTask1 = client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/1", content);
var responseTask2 = client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/2", content);
var responseTask3 = client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/2", content);

await Task.WhenAll(responseTask1, responseTask2, responseTask3);
```

I'm not certain it will be as "simultaneous" as you need, but worth trying out.